# Trigger events from render Backbone.View method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, triggers, backbone-views

I have a Backbone.View `block` instance with render method:

```
render: function() {
        this.$el.html(_.template(this.tpl, this.model.toJSON())).removeClass('load');
        this.trigger('render', this);
        return this;
    }
```

And add listener for this instance like this:

```
block = new App.View.Block();

button = new App.View.Button();
button.listenTo(button, 'render', button.refresh);
```

But trigger `render` not firing.

View `block` is rendering from `initialize()` method. If i call directly `block.trigger('render')`, listenTo will work

Comment: I'm not sure, but, if you call `render()` inside `initialize()` the event `render` was triggered before you attach the `.listenTo()` at the view.
If you fired `block.trigger('render')` after you attach `.listenTo()` it works fine, sure?

Comment: It's not clear from what you've shown which view this render function belongs to, the block or the button?

Comment: @kinakuta is Right! I assume that `button()` has `render()` like the method above

Comment: `render` it's the `block` method, guys, I'm sorry!

Comment: ... you solve your problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

Render the button when the block is rendered?

```
block  = new App.View.Block();
button = new App.View.Button();

// have the button listen to its parent, and render itself (same as refreshing)
button.listenTo( block, 'render', button.render );
```